# Display single message in all validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I user validation method in my codeigniter project.
In that i set rules for validation like.

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');`
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');`
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');`

Here display three difference errors when validation failed.
I want to display only one error like 'All fields are required' instead of follwing three.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute required in your inputs, so you don't need to send data to the server to get it checked.

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" required />
```

and you'll get on every input a message saying that it's required.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'All fields are required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'All fields are required'); // using this we overrideerror message found in the language file
```

Comment: Hi mohit I try your code to put in my controller file but it's not working.

Comment: put above this three line $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');